# How to manipulate components of just one column in a txt file

Tags: shell, unix

In a folder I have some txt files with 3 columns. I'm wondering if it is possible to append a character (say L) to all components of the third column. I managed to do it in matlab, but for those numbers consisting of less than 3 digit, like 81 , it appears as `L 81` however,the space after `L` is not desired for me. Im wondering if there is a way to do it in UNIX/shell? The files look like

```
0 1400000 165
1400000 1700000 336
1700000 2500000 216
2500000 3000000 228
3000000 3900000 366
3900000 4100000 108
4100000 4900000 250
4900000 5100000 81
```

I want them to be

```
0 1400000 L165
1400000 1700000 L336
1700000 2500000 L216
2500000 3000000 L228
3000000 3900000 L366
3900000 4100000 L108
4100000 4900000 L250
4900000 5100000 L81
```

Comment: what is column separator? a single space?

Comment: yes they are space separated

Comment: what is your shell? bash?

Comment: Im sorry i tried many times to comment, but it was not possible, anyways, it is bash

Comment: use `-i` option to save result to same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` more simply like this to substitute the second space for a space followed by `L`

```
sed 's/ / L/2' yourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sed` to add `L` after the second space :

```
$ sed -r 's/(.* .* )/\1L/' file 
0 1400000 L165
1400000 1700000 L336
1700000 2500000 L216
2500000 3000000 L228
3000000 3900000 L366
3900000 4100000 L108
4100000 4900000 L250
4900000 5100000 L81
```

to save result to same file use `-i` :

```
$ sed -i -r 's/(.* .* )/\1L/' file
```

Comment: Ok, really sorry guys for inconvenience, I'll do that from next time.